# Rutas en Laravel con frontend React

Tags: php, laravel

La ruta por defecto en web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

Trae por defecto cookies y el csrf, pero yo no necesito eso ya que voy a hacer el front con React. ¿Como tendría que hacerlo, debería copiar esta ruta a api.php?

Comment: Depende de como plantees el front. Lo que hago generalmente para una api es retornar los datos. Por ej: `Route::get('/', function() {return ['greetings' => 'Welcome to My API'];}]);`.

Comment: Quiero tenerlo todo junto así que necesito esa vista para cargar el script de React.

Comment: No sé si entiendo bien, pero en `web.php` puedes poner una ruta así `Route::get('{any}', function () { return view('welcome'); })->where('any', '^(?!api).*');` y en la vista welcome quita todo lo que no necesites y carga el script.

Comment: Eso creo que sería, para que funcionasen las rutas de React

Comment: Voy a hacer el preset con React, para cargar el React hay que cargar la vista con el script y in contenedor, el problema es que esa vista se carga en web.php y trae consigo las cookies y el csrf, que no los necesito porque voy a usar tokens jwt. Mi duda es si puedo cargar la vista en API.php en vez de web.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu [App\Http\Kernel.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/c15a5ee0d205ade08ad86174cb9c38aafd2bd226/app/Http/Kernel.php#L36) comenta la línea del middleware de Csrf.

En cuanto a las cookies deberías plantearte primero si realmente no las requiere como soporte a tu método de autenticación de usuarios. No van peleadas las cookies con el aplicativo de React. De hecho te facilitan en muchos casos la autenticación.

Pero realmente ese es todo un tema distinto, para una pregunta diferente una vez que hayas considerado como vas a proteger la información a la que dan acceso tus rutas.